# async await exception catching but still 404 error with red marks display

Tags: javascript, async-await

The below code catches the error but still 404 error with red marks displays in console, is that the way it works or only the log info of catch block should be displayed?

Or any other better way to handle the exception?

```
async function showList(req, err) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/poosts') // 'posts' to get work the url
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(response.statusText);
        }
        const data = await response.json()
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            const divInject = `
          <div>
              <h3>${data[i].title}</h3>
              <div>${data[i].body}</div>
          </div>
  `;
            const divInside = document.getElementById('append')
            divInside.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', divInject)
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};

showList();
```

Comment: FYI, `async`/`await` are in ES2017, which is also called ES8 (not ES7, which was ES2016).

Comment: The console tab is a network tab (HTTP), it has nothing to do with javascript at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but still 404 error with red marks displays in console

Yes, that's how it works. Regardless of whether you handle the 404, it's reported in the Network tab and also (on some browsers) the console (separately from your own `console.log`). You're successfully catching the exception. If you weren't, you'd *also* have a warning of an unhandled promise rejection in the console.